# Save EditText to file with Button - Android, Java

Tags: java, android, file, save, android-edittext

I have an EditText in which the user inputs their name, then i want to push a button and the content of the EditText is transferred into a file.

**EDITED**: I have this code so far:

```
Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.baddNametoFile);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                try{ 
                    ETName.getText().toString();

                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(

                        new FileWriter("/sdcard/Accelerometer.html", true)));
                writer.println("<h3 style=padding-left:20px;>" + ETName
                        + "</h3><br>");
                // new arraylist
                writer.close();

                }catch (IOException e) {
                    // put notification here later!!!
                    e.printStackTrace(); }
            }

        });
```

I have it printing to the file what the actual android value is:

```
android.widget.Button{......./baddNametoFile}
```

But that is just a placeholder to know the print works. I would like to see what the user has typed printed there instead.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ETName is probably EditText. You didnt post to much code so it should be like:
 `ETName.getText().toString();` Change `View ETName` in `View v` (it is click on a button not on a EditText). Lets try like this:

```
     @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try{   
    String etName =  ETName.getText().toString();
if(!etName.trim().equals("")){
                            File file =new File("/sdcard/Accelerometer.html");

                            //if file doesnt exists, then create it
                            if(!file.exists()){
                                file.createNewFile();
                            }


                            FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
                                BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
                                bufferWritter.write(etName);
                                bufferWritter.close();
                } 
                        }catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace(); }


                    }
```

Comment: Sorry, yeah ETName is the EditText i'm trying to get the content to save from

Comment: then try with: ETName.getText().toString();  I hope it will help you. Mark answer as useful if you find it helpful.

Comment: I have edited the code in the question. however, when i push the button to record the text the app crashes. There are many errors in LogCat:

Comment: copy your logcat here.

Comment: Do you have this file in that path:"/sdcard/Accelerometer.html"?

Comment: 11-10 16:14:19.626: E/AndroidRuntime(16516): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 16:14:19.626: E/AndroidRuntime(16516): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-10 16:14:19.626: E/AndroidRuntime(16516):  at sample.ble.sensortag.demo.DemoAccelerometerSensorActivity$1.onClick(DemoAccelerometerSensorActivity.java:102)
11-10 16:14:19.626: E/AndroidRuntime(16516):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
11-10 16:14:19.626: E/AndroidRuntime(16516):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
11-10 16:14:19.626: E/AndroidRuntime(16516):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730

Comment: Ok, what is in line 102 in DemoAccelero‌​meterSensorActivity.java?

Comment: I had the code you gave me, ETName.getText().toString(); in there but pretty sure that's wrong isn't it. Would I put that where I print ( + ETName.getText().toString(); )

Comment: I edit my answer, check it out. You should check if that String from EditText is not null, so write String etName =  ETName.getText().toString();  if(etName!=null){//rest of a code}  or if(!etName.equals("")){//rest of a code}

Comment: It gives me many errors again. It does not seem to like 
String etName =  ETName.getText().toString(); 
Sorry to be bothering you for so long, I'm new to Java and Android.

Comment: Thanks for Helping :D I changed the code and added some of my own and it worked!! There's only a small hiccup I should be able to fix. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
 try{

    File dir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/MyApp/");

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdir();
         System.out.println("Directory created");
      } 
    //ceate .rtf file with header
    myFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/MyApp/Student.rtf");

    if (!myFile.exists()) {
        myFile.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("File created");
    }

    fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
    myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

    //Write the header : in your case it is : Student class Marsk (only one time)
    myOutWriter.write("Student,class,Marks"+"\n");
    myOutWriter.flush();

   }catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```